# Matlab Multiplication

Tags: matlab, matrix

If matrix A is in X, and matrix B is in Y.

Doing a multiplcation would just be Z = X*Y. Correct assuming same size for both arrays.

How can I compute it doing it with a for loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The anwser by ja72 is wrong, see my comments under it to see why. In general, in these simple linear algebra operations, it's impossible for your code to beat the vectorized version, not even if you write your code in C/mex (unless you have a certain sparsity structure in your matrix that you can exploit in your code).  The reason is that under the hood, Matlab passes the actual job of matrix multiplication to Lapack library, written in Fortran, which then calls Blas libraries that are optimized given particular machine architecture.

Answer (score 3):

Yes acai is correct, and I remember wondering the same thing when I started using Matlab.  Just to provide some more detail to what acai said, LAPACK is Linear Algebra PACKage and is something a lot of other languages use to solve these types of problems, Python connects to it using SciPy, Java jlapack, etc..  BLAS is Basic Linear Algebra Subroutines, which handle the basic problem of matrix multiplication you are asking about.  Acai is also right that you can never beat the performance Matlab gives for matrix multiplication, this is their bread and butter and they have spent decades now, optimizing the performance of these operations.

Answer (score 1):

Yes matrix multiplication is `A*B` and element by element is `A*.B`. If A is (NxM) and B is (MxK) size then the code for `C=A*B` is

**update**

```
for i=1:N
  for j=1:K
    C(i,j) = A(i,:)*B(:,j)
  end
end
```

Comment: awesome! How come doing a for loop is a bit faster than doing the A*B?

Comment: Is the for loop being more cache friendly?

Comment: In fact to make the loop faster you switch the `i` and `j` loops making the 1st array index change the fastest. This has to do with how arrays are stored in memory.

Comment: Maybe the built in `*` operator has out of range checks and other overhead that is  missing from the loop, making it slower but more robust.

Comment: It's faster because it's wrong! it should be for i=1:N, now you are only executing the loop for one iteration, not N.

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis, Actually I did with a 3x3 times a 3x2 matrix and it gave me the right result. Oh well, I updated the answer.